# JFreeChart: no such method error despite having loaded the library

Tags: java, swing, runtime-error, jfreechart

I am using JFreeChart in a Java swing application. I did specify where the libraries are in my builder.xml file:

```
<zipgroupfileset dir="../lib" includes="jfreechart-0.9.21.jar" />
<zipgroupfileset dir="../lib" includes="jcommon-1.0.8.jar" />
```

I imported those libraries; Eclipse doesn't show any compilation error. But I am getting this when I run the code:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries.<init>(Ljava/lang/Comparable;)V
```

Could someone please help me figure out what's going on? Thank you!

Comment: Seems to be a version mismatch between jfreechart and jcommon. Did u try downloading latest versions of both jars? There can also be a different jcommon jar version in the classpath.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Note that `JCommon` classes have been integrated into `JFreeChart` [version 1.5](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart).

When downloading old releases from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreechart/files/), be sure to use *compatible* versions: For example, the latest `JFreeChart` JAR, `jfreechart-1.0.19`, should be used with the latest `JCommon` JAR, `jcommon-1.0.23`. You should see the correct `JCommon` JAR in the `lib` folder of whichever `JFreeChart` you choose.

The current version can be obtained via [mvn](/questions/tagged/mvn) or built as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69653678/230513).