# Output JFreeChart with JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, jfilechooser, javax.imageio

I have a JFreeChart plot that I would like to save as a PNG file from a Java swing application.

```
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot)chart.getPlot();
plot.setBackgroundPaint(new Color(255,228,196));
ChartPanel panel = new ChartPanel(chart);
setContentPane(panel);
panel.setSize(600, 300);

JFileChooser exportChooser = new JFileChooser();
exportChooser.setSelectedFile(new File("test plot"));
FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("PNG File","png");
exportChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
int returnVal = exportChooser.showDialog(null, "Export");
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
File file = exportChooser.getSelectedFile();
try {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(out, chart, panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight());
}catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}catch (Throwable t){
  t.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

I got this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Ljava/awt/image/RenderedImage;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/OutputStream;)
```

I am not sure what this means or how to resolve it. I am also not sure if my code makes sense, specifically `OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);`. Would really appreciate any insights!

Comment: Why not `ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG()`?

Comment: @trashgod the error still persisted....

Comment: Works for me; a missing library sounds like a `JFreeChart` installation issue, mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53145666/230513), or a  Java installation issue.

Comment: What Java version are you running? What is the output of `java --version` in the runtime environment that you get the error? Seems like a JRE issue.

Comment: @haraldK
java 10.0.2 
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)

Comment: Weird. Are you sure the `java.desktop` module is part of this JRE? It's now possible to include/exclude modules, and create a tailored, minimal JRE exactly for your needs, using the `jlink` tool.

Comment: @haraldK I could comprehend your comment a bit only after reading an article about Java 9's modularity feature (sorry for the late response). But how do I make sure it's part of the JRE? I also decided to try ImageIO but ran into a method-not-found error; I made a post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230998/imageio-found-in-launcher-but-not-elsewhere. Don't know if what you were talking about is related?